# gulp is not processing sass to correct directory

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-ruby-sass

Ok so everything used to work just fine on a diff computer and after switching I ended up having to install everything again.  Now I read through the tutorial to install gulp and it actually works with javascript files but for some odd reason my sass compiles in a weird output and actually the file is not there..so not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    del = require('del');

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    return sass('public/sass/')
        .pipe( autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe( minifycss() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest('public/css/'))
        .pipe( notify({message: '¡Styles complete!'}));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){

    var files = [
        'public/js-source/vendor/jquery.min.js',
        'public/js-source/vendor/modernizr.custom.js',
        'public/js-source/vendor/bootstrap.min.js',
        'public/js-source/vendor/bootstrap-modal.js',
        'public/js-source/vendor/bootstrap-modalmanager.js',
        'public/js-source/vendor/bootstrap-slider.js',
        'public/js-source/vendor/bootstrap-toggle.min.js',
        'public/js-source/vendor/date.js',
        'public/js-source/vendor/datepicker.js'


    ];

    gulp.src( files )
        .pipe( concat('concat.js') )
        .pipe( gulp.dest('public/js/'))
        .pipe( uglify() )
        .pipe( rename('concat.min.js') )
        .pipe( gulp.dest('public/js/'))
        .pipe( notify({message: '¡Scripts complete!'}));

});

gulp.task('default', ['styles']);

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('public/sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('public/js-source/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
```

And when i modify any scss file to test out the output it does the following:

```
[19:48:59] write ./.css/bootstrap.css
[19:49:02] write ./.css/landing.css
[19:49:07] write ./.css/style.css
```

So I'm completely clueless as to what it is..

Comment: Which version of `gulp-ruby-sass` are you using? can you run in verbose mode and update your question with the entire log? https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass#verbose

Comment: sorry just saw this, but i installed the latest and even ran a gulp update command to make sure it was latest, is there anything else that might help?